# How many public repositories can be made on GitHub for individual account?

Tags: git, github

I was interested to know, how many public repositories can be created on GitHub for an individual account (not an organization account). Is their any limit on number of public repositories that can be created on GitHub.

Answer (score 36):

THe ["What plan should I choose?" page](https://help.github.com/articles/what-plan-should-i-choose/) mentions:

> GitHub provides two types of plans: free plans and paid plans.
>
> Both plans have the exact same features. **They can have any number of public repositories, with unlimited collaborators.**

That being said, *too much* of anything will be eventually detected and reviewed by GitHub in order to check if the service isn't abused.

Update April 2020: as I explained in "[Can a repository on GitHub be owned by 2 users?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61215568/6309)", "[**GitHub is now free for teams**](https://github.blog/2020-04-14-github-is-now-free-for-teams/)".
The number of public or private repo is now unlimited.

Answer (score 8):

Theoretically, everyone can has an **unlimited** number of **public and private repositories** even **as part of a free plan**.

**Public repositories** don't have officially **any restrictions even as part of a free plan**.

[image]

Source: [Pricing / Plans for all developers](https://github.com/pricing)

Answer (score 3):

An individual GitHub account can have unlimited number of repositories

Comment: This does not add any additional information when compared to the already existing answers.

Comment: please try to elaborate more.

Answer (score 3):

You can have unlimitted Private as well as Public repos in github free. But still there are limitations for private repos like you dont get protected branches , wikis, pages, insight etc.

You can get these by upgrading to GitHub Pro in your individual account itself you dont have to switch to an organisation account.