# Can a repository on github be owned by 2 users?

Tags: git, github

Last year I was involved in a project with another group member. 
She created a repo in her personal account and added me as a contributor. 
I can still access the repo and view its contents but I have to go through her account.

I would like the repo to also appear on my account. 
I see you can Transfer repos but will that mean that it then no longer appear on her account?
Or is the simpler solution just to clone the repository and upload it to my account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look here for GitHub pricing information:

https://github.com/pricing

The free/Individual version allows for up to three "collaborators".  That should be exactly what you're looking for.

The team versions, on the other hand, allow for multiple collaborators *AND* "user management".  If you wanted finer control over what collaborators can and cannot do, you'd need a team version.

Q: So what's a collaborator?

> A: [Contributors vs
>   Collaborators](https://github.com/CoolProp/CoolProp/wiki/Contributors-vs-Collaborators)
>
> - **Contributor**: A contributor is someone from the outside not on the core development team of the project that wants to contribute some
>     changes to a project.
> - **Collaborator**: A collaborator is someone on the core development team of the project and has commit access to the main repository of
>     the project.
>
> Continue reading to learn about the workflow for both contributors and
>   collaborators.
>
> - [Contributing Workflow](https://github.com/CoolProp/CoolProp/wiki/Contributing%3A-git-development-workflow)
> - [Collaboration Workflow](https://github.com/CoolProp/CoolProp/wiki/Collaborating%3A-git-development-workflow)

I use the free/Individual version for my personal use - it's everything I need.

And sure - you can always clone a repository from a different account, do a "git add remote" of your local clone to the "other account".

Comment: I agree, the free version is all I need too. I'll read up a bit more on collaboration. But if I don't come right I'll just use the clone route because we're not working on it anymore. I just want to beef up my account a bit more. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the same question as here: [add-another-user-to-project-owners-in-github](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8015579/add-another-user-to-project-owners-in-github)

> You can only add collaborators to your repository. It cannot be "co-owned".
>
> But when someone is added as collaborator to a repo, that repo will be listed in the Your Repositories section ( but the username will be the owner username only)
>
> The only way for doing what you want is to fork the repo and collaborate through pull requests.
>
> wrote by @manojlds

Comment: It is actually similar to that question. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> The team versions, on the other hand, allow for multiple collaborators AND "user management". If you wanted finer control over what collaborators can and cannot do, you'd need a team version.

True, but at least the collaborators are no longer limited.

Since April 14th 2020: "[**GitHub is now free for teams**](https://github.blog/2020-04-14-github-is-now-free-for-teams/)":

> We’re happy to announce we’re making private repositories with unlimited collaborators available to all GitHub accounts.
>   **All of the core GitHub features are now free for everyone.**
>
> Until now, if your organization wanted to use GitHub for private development, you had to subscribe to one of our paid plans. But every developer on earth should have access to GitHub. Price shouldn’t be a barrier.
>
> This means teams can now manage their work together in one place: CI/CD, project management, code review, packages, and more. We want everyone to be able to ship great software on the platform developers love.
>
> Teams who need advanced features (like code owners), enterprise features (like SAML), or personalized support can upgrade to one of our paid plans.

---

Since May 2020, [ownership transfert is being tested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61689156/6309).

Answer (score 0):

Our Github repo was grandfathered in at $25 a month for the organization from like 2010. (I might be exaggerating but maybe not!)

There's no way to add new owners and get the latest features (like draft PRs) without updating to a new monthly plan.

I think what we are paying for is now free. So check and see if you are using the old plan, and then ask your administrator to update the plan.

This is what I am running into, so maybe someone else has this issue.
Just need to spend the time to sell this to my boss!